# TYPO3 htmlArea RTE fill with content

Tags: typo3, rte, jhtmlarea

I create in my TYPO3 Extension a RTE Editor ( http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/rtehtmlarea_api_manual/2.2.0/view/6/1/ ) and it's works fine.

But how I can put Content in the RTE? Like a "Hello World".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put some default content to the DB field for which you are using the RTE, you can do that in your extension OR using `TCAdefaults`